# Как считать выделенный текст на Delphi с WindowsApi?

Tags: winapi, delphi

Какая функция winapi в delphi вернет выделенный в системе текст?
[image: вернет выделенный]

Например на картинке результат будет "вернет выделенный"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В зависимости от того, с какого элемента управления хотите считать текст.
Для `rich edit control` попробуйте [`EM_GETSELTEXT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/bb774190(v=vs.85).aspx).
[`Edit Control`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775458(v=vs.85).aspx) - [`EM_GETSEL`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761598(v=vs.85).aspx).
Еще, тема на stackoverflow: [Get selected text using SendMessage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13047556/get-selected-text-using-sendmessage?rq=1).

Answer (score 1):

Если речь идёт о чужом TextBox'е, то получить позиции начала и конца выделения можно так:

```vb
Public Enum WinMsgs As Integer
  WmHotkey = &H312
  EmGetsel = &HB0
  EmSetsel = &HB1
End Enum

Public Declare Unicode Function SendMessageVV Lib "user32" Alias "SendMessageW" (ByVal hwnd As IntPtr, ByVal wMsg As Integer, ByVal wParam As IntPtr, ByVal lParam As IntPtr) As Integer
Public Declare Unicode Function SendMessageRR Lib "user32" Alias "SendMessageW" (ByVal hwnd As IntPtr, ByVal wMsg As Integer, ByRef wParam As Integer, ByRef lParam As Integer) As Integer

Private ActiveWindowHandle As IntPtr = 0, ActiveControlHandle As IntPtr
Dim SelStart As Integer, SelEnd As Integer

AttachThreadInput(OtherPrcId, MyPrcId, 1)
ActiveControlHandle = GetFocus()
SendMessageRR(ActiveControlHandle, WinMsgs.EmGetsel, SelStart, SelEnd)

AttachThreadInput(OtherPrcId, MyPrcId, 0)
```